# There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'OdeToFood''

Tags: asp.net-core

Im trying add new controller , but i got this error. How can i solve this? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgjPV.png)

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\OdeToFood.Data\OdeToFood.Data.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.2">
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Pages\Api\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

dotnet restore didn't work, clearing the componentcache didn't work

Comment: Be sure the packages' version match the TargetFramework.

Comment: Thanks so much! i will check today.